# Power Relation $\ge$ on the Set of Natural numbers

Tags: discrete-mathematics, relations

Good afternoon,

I am having trouble defining the following:

> Let $R$ denote the binary relation $\ge$ on the set of Natural Numbers $\mathbb N$.
>       Find $R^2$.

What I have so far for R:

> $R= \{\langle a,b\rangle\mid a \in R \land b \in R \land (a\ge b) \}$
>
> Inductive clause: For numbers $x$ and $y$ in $R$, if $\langle x,y\rangle$ is in $R$, then $\langle x+1,y\rangle$ is in $R$ and $\langle x+1, y+1\rangle$ is in $R$. 
>       Extremal clause: Nothing is in R unless it is obtained from the Basis and Inductive clause.

Thanks, David

Comment: What are your thoughts? Have you considered just plugging in the definitoin of $R^2$ as a starter?

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen I have edited with my thoughts so far.

Comment: You’re looking in the wrong direction: no induction is needed (or wanted) here.

Comment: @user113954 : What is $R^2$ to begin with?  I have never seen this notation and neither have at least two other commenters.  Normally it would mean $R \times R$, but that doesn't seem to make sense here.  You need to define $R^2$ _in the question_, not just in a comment.

Comment: @user11394 : Also, your equation starting with $R = \{ \langle a, b \rangle$ makes no sense because the elements of $R$ are ordered pairs of elements of $R$!  Unless $R$ is empty, this probably violates some axiom of ZF set theory.

Answer (score 1):

HINT: **Always start with the definition(s)**; at this level that’s often all that you need. Let $m,n\in\Bbb N$; then by definition $\langle m,n\rangle\in R^2$ if and only if there is a $k\in\Bbb N$ such that $\langle m,k\rangle\in R$ and $\langle k,n\rangle\in R$. Now rewrite this using the more familiar $\le$ instead of $R$, and see what it tells you about $m$ and $n$.

Comment: Thanks Brian. Would the following be correct:
<m,n> ∈R2 iff there is a k∈N such that ⟨m,k⟩∈R and ⟨k,n⟩∈R where n ≥ m.

Comment: @user113954: The first part of it is true by definition: $\langle m,n\rangle\in R^2$ iff there is a $k\in\Bbb N$ such that $\langle m,k\rangle,\langle k,n\rangle\in R$. It isn’t clear exactly what you mean by the last bit. Are you trying to say that there is such a $k$ iff $m\ge n$, or did you mean something else?

Comment: Yes, I meant m ≥ n. Is this an acceptable way to also define the 1 step transitive closure on the Relation?

Comment: @user113954: I’m still not entirely sure that you’re actually seeing what $R^2$ is; let’s clear that up before we deal with the transitive closure. What is the difference, if any, between $R$ and $R^2$?

Comment: The relation R is a NxN on the ≥ operation. R^2 is the composite ralation from R to R.

Comment: @user113954: Okay, you’re not seeing it. You know that $m\,R^2\,n$ iff there is a $k\in\Bbb N$ such that $m\ge k$ and $k\ge n$. There is a very simple description of such pairs of $m$ and $n$, one that doesn’t mention $R$ by name at all. Can you find such a description?

Comment: It sounds like the sandwich theorem to me! The concept makes sense to me, but I'm not sure of the specific name you are referring.

Comment: @user113954: You’re looking in the wrong direction altogether. I’m asking for a simple description of the relation $R^2$, one that does not mention $R$ by name at all, not for some theorem. Here’s another hint: can you find natural numbers $m$ and $n$ such that $\langle m,n\rangle\in R^2$ but $\langle m,n\rangle\notin R$, or such that $\langle m,n\rangle\in R$ but $\langle m,n\rangle\notin R^2$?

Comment: Are you asking me to explicitly list those pairs? @brian

Comment: @user113954: If such a pair exists, I’m asking for a specific example; if no such pair exists, I’m asking for an explanation of how you know.

Comment: No, there are no pairs that exist. For every m ^ n ∈ R, there exists all possibilities of n, where m ≥ n.

Comment: @user113954: I’m going to ignore the second sentence, because it simply does not make sense, and focus on the first. If no such pairs exist, what is the ordinary, everyday symbol for the relation $R^2$? (We can come back to the second sentence later, if you want.)

Comment: Maybe put it in other words: If I gave you two specific 100digit natural numbers $n,m$, how fast would you be able to tell wether or not $(n,m)\in R^2$ and how would you arrive at your answer as smart as possible?